# Old reflex to digital

Tags: nikon, digital-vs-film

I have an old Nikon Nikkormat reflex film camera. It's an object of sentimental value more than else, but I would like to know if it's possible to "convert" it to digital. Something like a fake film with a digital sensor on it...